# document.getElementById("Three").parentNode.previousSibling.setAttribute giving me issues

Tags: javascript

Using Chrome I am trying to target another element of a list

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="One">One</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="Two">Two</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="Three">Three</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="Four">Four</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="Five">Five</a></li>
</ul>
```

So this works,

```
document.getElementById("Three").parentNode.setAttribute("class", "active");
```

However This doesn't and I"m confused why.

```
document.getElementById("Three").parentNode.previousSibling.setAttribute("class", "active");
```

Here is the error I get in my console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Text> has no method 'setAttribute'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previous sibling of the `<li>` that is the parent element is a text node (containing a line break), which doesn't have a `setAttribute()` method.

That line of JS will work if you remove any white space from between the elements like this:

```
<li><a href="#" id="Two">Two</a></li><li><a href="#" id="Three">Three</a></li>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HLGJE/

But you probably don't want your markup all on one line, so you could try something like this to skip over the text node(s):

```
var prev = document.getElementById("Three").parentNode.previousSibling;
while(prev.nodeType == 3)
    prev = prev.previousSibling;
prev.setAttribute("class", "active");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HLGJE/2/

Comment: You can actually *see* this text node if you have any whitespace between two inline, non-floated elements. http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/k6fca/

Comment: Thanks, this helps me fix the issue. I am new to JS and am trying to figure out the best way to understand how to target things around the dom. I don't really comprehend whats going on here other than remove the spacing because JS thinks its text.

Comment: It's not that _JS_ thinks it is text, it _is_ text. Text (including whitespace) between other elements is a "text node", which you can access via JS - which is as it should be because otherwise how could you manipulate it if you wanted to do something with the text? That may seem a bit silly when the "text" is just whitespace, but consider something like `<p><i>Hello</i> there how are <b>you</b> today?</p>` - in between the `<i>` and `<b>` elements is some text that isn't in its own element - it belongs to the `<p>`, of course, but then so does the text after the `<b>` element...